# Using two yeoman generators in one project?

Tags: yeoman

Is it possible to use 2 yeoman generators in a single project? I want to use generator-angular and generator-node-express-mongo in a single project. Is this a good idea or its much easier to go with 2 separate projects?

Comment: You mean that you'll let two generators generate stuff into the same directory? If they try to generate the same file names you might get issues, but if they don't it might work just fine... have you tried it? Testing won't hurt, you can always start over.

Comment: I tried it and it creates conflicts in bower.json, package.json and GruntFile.js. The conflicts in bower,json and package.json are easy to merge but GruntFile.js is a major effort. Don't know if there is any easier way.

Comment: It sounds like the easiest way is to write the gruntfile yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is YES. But some cases need to take in account like the use of two different JS-MV* frameworks like Angularjs and ember or build systems like gulp and grunt

Check this answer too:
[Using two yeoman generators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365409/using-two-yeoman-generators)